# Notification Animation in Android

Tags: android

I want to create Notification Animation in Android. I have done a sample application using below link,

[Animation in Notification bar Custom View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688052/animation-in-notification-bar-cutsom-view)

It's working fine only on Motorola Droid Razr (v 4.0.3). Remaining devices are not working as expected. Please let me know if you have any solution.

Thanks,