# Does Android have an Internet status turning circle in the top bar like the iPhone has?

Tags: java, android, iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

The iPhone has this swirling icon, which you can make appear when the Internet is working behind in the background. It's a VERY simple call to turn it on/off.

Does Android have anything like this? How do I call it and how does it work?

[image]

Comment: Most android devices already have a network usage graphic in the status bar which displays when the device is sending\ receiving data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should display this in the ActionBar.

The simplest way

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

Or using ActionBarSherlock for backwards compatibility

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, i haven't seen it on android yet. However with ICS and above, we see 2 arrows accompanying the WiFi or 3G to indicate if there is activity on the network. However it may not be possible to programmatically control it.

You could otherwise use a indeterminate progress bar within your activity to show background work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Android Notifications and use an AnimationDrawable. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8764950/265375). (Note that I haven't tried it).