# How to create wifi data sending and receving arrow animation in Android?

Tags: android, android-wifi

i am working on WIFI Custom setting creation in android i want to create wifi 
data sending receiving arrow which shows data packet sending and receiving , which is visible when we connect with WiFi like Samsung phones.

Please tell me how i can create this function .

Enclosed screen shot for reference.

Thanks in advance [image]

Comment: So you want to show this animation when wifi gets connected to a network? Check the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688052/animation-in-notification-bar-cutsom-view

Comment: May be but my need is when data packet sending or receiving on that time animation will play

Comment: No Sanjeeb i have used this but this play continuously with a particular duration buyt i want when data packet send or receiving then it show animation

Comment: check when you are sending data then show up animation but when you are receving that time show down button.