# Android use Google Play notification install icon

Tags: android, android-notifications

When installing an app via Google Play the progress notification icon is an arrow being filled from top to bottom without a progress bar. I followed this link:

http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/display-progress.html

However I was unable to display an install notification without a progress bar.
Is there a way to use the same icon used by Google Play when it installs an app?
I don't want to create a custom animation for the icon. I want to use the same resource Google Play uses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animation in Notification bar Cutsom View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688052/animation-in-notification-bar-cutsom-view)

Comment: No. I don't want to create a custom. I want to use the same assets they are using which I imagine should be accessible.

Comment: Why it should be accessible? AFAIK google play application is separate application which not part of android. Source code of google play is not published - so just find something similar or make it by yourself.

Comment: I know that Google Play services is proprietary. I'm inquiring whether the icon is hidden in play services or in the android platform.

Comment: I couldn't find it and am asking for assistance.

Comment: Than create/modify proper question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html#stat_sys_download or go to /path_to_sdk/platforms/android-{version}/data/res/stat_sys_download and copy xml file with corresponding
 png files to your project, in order to protect it from device manufacturers modifications.

Answer (score 0):

For example you want to create a notification for downloading some files with a animated icon like Google Play:

```
mBuilder.setContentTitle("Downloading... ")
            .setContentText("Please wait...")
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)  // here is the animated icon
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)).build();
```