# How to add animated icon to contentView of download notification?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I know I could have animated download icon in status bar when downloading a file by using the default android resource `android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download`. My question is how to have this animated icon in the contentView of download notification? Like when you are downloading a file with Chrome.

[image: animated icon in notification contentView]

I attempted to display the resourse using ImageView but it does not support animated icons and the icon was displayed like an ordinary icon with no animations.

Comment: visit this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037962/how-to-animate-the-progress-notification-icon

Comment: but I want animated icon to be displayed in content view of the notification. I already have the resource in the status bar as I said. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. You should use notification styling. Icon is one of the major components in the notification which android sets its style. So in addition to use `android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download` as icon resource, you should use `.setStyle` even if you have custom notification layout.

```
    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelID)
            .setCustomContentView(collapsedView)
            .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW);
```