# Animation-list does not work with custom drawables

Tags: android

I have an animation list that is working fine, however it's using from the google default vector drawables:

[image]

As you can see these are the default vector drawables provided by google. It's the wifi drawable at different stages defined by the colors 0%, 33%, 66%, 99%.
But as soon as I use custom drawables with photoshopped colors the animation-list longer works:

[image]

The above doesn't create an animation at all. All my java code is the same, the first picture is all imported `.SVG` second image is also all imported `.SVG`. How come the second one with custom images doesn't work?

Comment: Can you share of your converted .SVG files - at least _ic_upload1_ and _ic_upload6_?

Comment: Sure https://pastebin.com/Yg4VS2Au

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appeas that you call it in `onCreate()` ,as mentioned in [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation)

> It's important to note that the start() method called on the AnimationDrawable cannot be called during the onCreate() method of your Activity, because the AnimationDrawable is not yet fully attached to the window. If you want to play the animation immediately, without requiring interaction, then you might want to call it from the onStart() method in your Activity, which will get called when Android makes the view visible on screen.

check [this](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/frame-animations-in-android/) for a similar sample

**Edit**
what I have discovered is if your `animation-list` contains more the one vector, you have to change `fillAlpha` for at least one path to make animation works as I think in your converted files it's always `android:fillAlpha="1"`
you can check the modified files [here](https://pastebin.com/uxSVn6tX)

Comment: I'm using it in ```NotificationCompat.Builder``` ```.setSmallIcon(R.animation.upload_animation)```. It works when I use the first animation list, but not the second list(with photoshopped drawables).

Comment: oh, I didn't know that you are using this in notification check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037962/how-to-animate-the-progress-notification-icon/) I thinks it's close , or you can convert your images to vectors using [this](https://vectormagic.com/) site

Comment: I already said they are converted to vectors, but they are still not working. Both lists are vectors, except only the first list works.

Comment: I think there is a problem in the conversion, I can't imagine other scenario

Comment: How would there be a conversion issue when I am using the built in conversion: https://i.imgur.com/q2BVWFg.png

Comment: Changing the ```fillAlpha``` values fixed it, thanks.